# FInd interval of date using pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have date

```
                     used_at  active_seconds  buy  
0        2014-07-02 00:00:04               6    1  
1        2014-07-02 00:00:10               6    1  
2        2014-07-02 00:00:16               8    1  
3        2014-07-02 00:00:24               4    0  
4        2014-07-02 00:00:25              32    0  
5        2014-07-02 00:00:28               4    0  
6        2014-07-02 00:00:32             236    0  
7        2014-07-02 00:00:52              69    1  
8        2014-07-02 00:01:23               6    0  
9        2014-07-02 00:01:33               2    1
```

I try `if buy == 1:` print data before this string, where month of date is equal to string(where buy == 1) or `month - 1`. 
I use

```
for i, (id, date, buy, url) in enumerate(zip(ids, dates, buys, urls)):
    if buys[i] == 1:
        buuy = str(id) + ' ' + str(date) + ' ' + str(buy) + ' ' + ":"
        print buuy
        print df.ix[dates[i-1]:dates[i].replace(month=date.month - 1, day=1)]
```

But it returns `KeyError: -1`
What's wrong?

Comment: IIUC it should be `date.dt.month` if it is of type `datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: @shivsn if I will use `print df[(df['used_at'] < dates[i]) & (df['used_at'] > dates[i].replace(month=date.month - 1, day=1))]`? why it print only this date?